# Функция setInterval в Opera

Tags: html, javascript, css

В общем, работает `setInterval` хорошо, однако вызовом `setInterval` меняются картинки, и суть в чем: в Опере при смене картинки курсор мыши меняет тип на загрузку, в итоге во всех браузерах нормально, а в Опере курсор, не переставая, в загрузке висит, что делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
var b = 10; 
var c = 23; 
var time = 70;
function alerte(be, imge){
    $(imge).attr("src", 'images/'+be+'.png');
    }
var inter1 = setInterval(function(){
    b=b+1;
        if (b>=c)
        {
           b=1;
           alerte(b, $('.result'));
        }
        else
        {
           alerte(b, $('.result'));
        }   
    },time);
```

Comment: под рукой нет Opera, но так быть не должно. Протестируйте, пожалуйста, следующий код в Опере: [http://jsfiddle.net/dMED6/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/dMED6/

Comment: картинки прогружаются сразу или с помощью аякса?

Comment: меянется src jsкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привел код к более-менее читабельному виду:

```
var b = 10;
var c = 23;
var time = 70;

function chngImgSrc() {
    b++;
    if (b>=c) b=1;
    $('.result').attr("src", 'images/'+b+'.png');  
}
setInterval(chngImgSrc,time);
```

Вам не кажется, что менять картинку каждые 70 милиссекунд - это слишком часто? Если, конечно, целью не является добиться 24 кадров в секунду :)
+ b в начале равно 10, а в цикле сбрасывается в 1. Но это так, мелочи...

Comment: нет б как раз как было ровно 10 так и осталось, а сбрасывается при условии, и цикл начинается с начала =)

Comment: но за оптимизацию спасибо, в общем проблему решил тем, что установил на html and body в css курсор default